# calculating fibonacci concurrently without channels, but pointers are not working

Tags: pointers, go, concurrency, fibonacci, goroutine

in this exercise I am trying to compute Fibonacci numbers but by spawning goroutines and sending back result by pointer in argument but I am doing something wrong please help

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fib(n int, p *int) {
    fmt.Println(n)
    var a, b int
    if n > 1 {
        go fib(n-1, &a)
        go fib(n-2, &b)
        *p = a + b
    } else {
        *p = n
    }
    fmt.Println(*p)

}

func main() {
    c := -1
    go fib(5, &c)
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Comment: The program has a data race.  Run the [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) to see where.

Comment: A fib calculation is a sequential one. Using go routines for this is not ideal and is redundant. Your code however has a data race. multiple go routines can read and write `p`. Also when you are spawning go routines, you want to wait for all of them to finish before exiting main. One way to do this is via waitgroups. Refer [this tutorial](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you @poWar below is my solution posted only to not leave question unanswered (probably not best but gets exercise done)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func fib(n int, p *int, wg1 *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // fmt.Println(n)
    a, b := -1, -1
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    if n > 1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go fib(n-1, &a, &wg)
        wg.Add(1)
        go fib(n-2, &b, &wg)
        wg.Wait()
        *p = a + b
    } else {
        *p = n
    }
    wg1.Done()
    // fmt.Println(*p)

}

func main() {
    c := -1
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go fib(30, &c, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```